# Tkinter is not known in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter

I am faced with **No module named 'Tkinter'** when using Python Anaconda 3.6. How can I access the module?
I am using Windows 7 with 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 0):

`import tkinter`

If you do not want to have to write tkinter. before each tkinter command:

`from tkinter import *`

Comment: You mean, if you want to pollute your namespace with loads of unknown names? No seriously, never import `*` from a module.